# elasticsearch query to extract namespace and log fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

Using `match_all` I can get the following from a local es cluster:

```
$ curl "http://127.0.0.1:9200/_search?pretty"   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -d'{ "query": { "match_all": {} }}'
{
  "took" : 9,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "kubernetes-2021.08.30",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "GSh-l3sBkJvTF8SCKo5f",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2021-08-30T14:37:05.020Z",
          "time" : "2021-08-30T14:37:05.020460752Z",
          "stream" : "stderr",
          "_p" : "F",
          "log" : "[2021/08/30 14:37:05] [error] [net] TCP connection failed: elasticsearch-master.elk.svc.cluster.local:9200 (Connection refused)",
          "kubernetes" : {
            "pod_name" : "fluent-bit-49z9h",
            "namespace_name" : "logging",
            "pod_id" : "02428324-c3e0-459e-bcc5-0c33af8db989",
            "labels" : {
              "app_kubernetes_io/instance" : "fluent-bit",
              "app_kubernetes_io/name" : "fluent-bit",
              "controller-revision-hash" : "74556bf9cf",
              "pod-template-generation" : "1"
            },
            "annotations" : {
              "checksum/config" : "f4a875e2e4705ad60e5dcc5c306e94891f9200db72649cff4020642d9df2ecf1",
              "checksum/luascripts" : "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"
            },
            "host" : "my-kind-worker",
            "container_name" : "fluent-bit",
            "docker_id" : "46f6f349cc5bed659c50f9d29a94a76376f9243c076cdd29dfbd7cc60c238149",
            "container_hash" : "docker.io/fluent/fluent-bit@sha256:10ea2709cef6e7059d980b4969d5f9d753ef97278a817c214cbe9120b1152082",
            "container_image" : "docker.io/fluent/fluent-bit:1.8.3"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "kubernetes-2021.08.30",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Gih-l3sBkJvTF8SCKo5f",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2021-08-30T14:37:05.020Z",
          "time" : "2021-08-30T14:37:05.020491241Z",
          "stream" : "stderr",
          "_p" : "F",
          "log" : "[2021/08/30 14:37:05] [error] [net] socket #64 could not connect to elasticsearch-master.elk.svc.cluster.local:9200",
          "kubernetes" : {
            "pod_name" : "fluent-bit-49z9h",
            "namespace_name" : "logging",
            "pod_id" : "02428324-c3e0-459e-bcc5-0c33af8db989",
            "labels" : {
              "app_kubernetes_io/instance" : "fluent-bit",
              "app_kubernetes_io/name" : "fluent-bit",
              "controller-revision-hash" : "74556bf9cf",
              "pod-template-generation" : "1"
            },
            "annotations" : {
              "checksum/config" : "f4a875e2e4705ad60e5dcc5c306e94891f9200db72649cff4020642d9df2ecf1",
              "checksum/luascripts" : "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"
            },
            "host" : "my-kind-worker",
            "container_name" : "fluent-bit",
            "docker_id" : "46f6f349cc5bed659c50f9d29a94a76376f9243c076cdd29dfbd7cc60c238149",
            "container_hash" : "docker.io/fluent/fluent-bit@sha256:10ea2709cef6e7059d980b4969d5f9d753ef97278a817c214cbe9120b1152082",
            "container_image" : "docker.io/fluent/fluent-bit:1.8.3"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For each hit I would like to just print the `log` and `namespace_name`. I have tried with:

```
$ curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:9200/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "_source": {
      "includes": [ "log", "kubernetes.namespace_name" ],
      "excludes": [ "_type" ]
    }
}
'
{
  "took" : 293,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "kubernetes-2021.08.30",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "GSh-l3sBkJvTF8SCKo5f",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "kubernetes" : {
            "namespace_name" : "logging"
          },
          "log" : "[2021/08/30 14:37:05] [error] [net] TCP connection failed: elasticsearch-master.elk.svc.cluster.local:9200 (Connection refused)"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "kubernetes-2021.08.30",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Gih-l3sBkJvTF8SCKo5f",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "kubernetes" : {
            "namespace_name" : "logging"
          },
          "log" : "[2021/08/30 14:37:05] [error] [net] socket #64 could not connect to elasticsearch-master.elk.svc.cluster.local:9200"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But even though I have  `"excludes": [ "_type" ]` its still part of the output.

How do I trim those unwanted fields from the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filter_path`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html) to modify your response result

```
POST/ http://localhost:9200/index-name/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source
 {
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "log",
      "kubernetes.namespace_name"
    ]
  }
}
```

The search result will be

```
{
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "_source": {
          "kubernetes": {
            "namespace_name": "logging"
          },
          "log": "[2021/08/30 14:37:05] [error] [net] socket #64 could not connect to elasticsearch-master.elk.svc.cluster.local:9200"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is that a POST and not a GET?